# C# protected internal method with internal return type?

Tags: c#

Does this mean `protected` method cannot be `internal` in a `public` type?

```
internal class InternalReturnType
{
}

public class PublicTypeWithProtectedMethod
{
    //build succeeded when I remove `protected`
    internal protected InternalReturnType GetValue()
    {
        return new InternalReturnType();
    }
}

public sealed class PublicTypeWithPublicMethod : PublicTypeWithProtectedMethod
{
    public void Print()
    {
        var value = base.GetValue();
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried to compile or launch this program ? What errors did you have ? What do you want to achieve ?

Comment: Why not try it out yourself?

Comment: To do this you would need your `InternalReturnType` class to inherit a publicly visible base class or interface, and have your `PublicTypeWithProtectedMethod.GetValue` method return this base class or interface.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`internal protected` means that the member is accessible from either the declaring assembly or from any derived type in **any** assembly. Since `InternalReturnType` is marked as `internal` it will only be accessible from the declaring assembly. This is why the compiler complains as it can't honor both restrictions, if you can access `GetValue` from any derived type in any assembly, you should be able to access `InternalReturnType` from any assembly, but it is marked as `internal` so it shouldn't be accessible from any assembly. You can either remove `protected` from the member or make `InternalReturnType` public.

**Note** Depending on what you are trying to do, you should have a look at [`private protected`](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mazhou/2017/10/05/c-7-series-part-5-private-protected/) (available on C# 7.2). This will allow access in derived types only within the assembly.

Comment: Thanks. and `private protected` are only available after C# 7.2, so I moved the internal method into another internal class, and call this public type instead.

Comment: @runerback added the version to the note to make things clear :)